# Unable to submit form using ajax while the same thing can be done easily without using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I have been trying to submit the form using ajax to the same .php file and when i am doing without ajax like directly form action then database is been updated, however when i am doing the same thing with ajax then no change in database.

HTML

```
    <form id="myfrm" autocomplete="off" style="margin-left:20px" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control required" name="personal-msg" type="text" placeholder="Your Personal Message"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control required" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name">
                  </div>
                </div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-danger-gradiant text-white border-0"><span> Create Account</span></button>
    
    
    </form>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/script.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('submit', '#myfrm', function(e) {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 200);
  $("#wait").css("display", "block");

  $.ajax({
    type: $(this).attr('method'),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(html) {
      $('#test').html(data);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#wait").css("display", "none");
        $(".main").remove();
        $(".right-image").remove();
        $(".reg-success").show();

      }, 2000);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      var err = JSON.parse("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
      alert(err.Message);
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

PHP

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
    
        //database stuff
}
     ?>
```

This is some parts of code and all in one file named example.php

Comment: What's in `var_dump($_POST);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this).serialize()` does not serialize submit buttons. Since you need it for you Sever side check you'll have to add it in

```
data: $(this).serialize()+'&submit=ajax',
```